# Start Tasks in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor early/ jump start

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java.util.concurrent, scheduledexecutorservice

I have an executor service that is periodically executing a bunch of tasks. They are initialised on startup and run every so often, so far so good.

I would like to now add functionality to jump start the execution of those tasks based on an event.

I found the decorateTask method which allows me to store the tasks I scheduled. However, I am not sure how I can get them to run?

I had the idea of overwriting the Delayed method in the RunnableScheduledFuture to have it return 0 on a predefined event, but I am also not sure if that is possible and how the executor would behave if I would do that?

Another idea would be to collect all tasks and then submit them for execution directly on an event. Also not sure how that would behave.

I can't just call run on them since they will run in the same thread.

I hope this all makes sense. Let me know if there's anything unclear.

```
public class EventBasedExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implements EventBasedExecutorService {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EventBasedExecutor.class);

private List<RunnableScheduledFuture<?>> workers = new ArrayList<>();

public EventBasedExecutor(int corePoolSize, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    super(corePoolSize, threadFactory);

}

@Override
protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Runnable runnable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
    workers.add(task);
    return super.decorateTask(runnable, task);
}

@Override
public void executeEarly() {
        // do something here to start the executors work  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most clean and easy for understanding way would be to collect all tasks and run them directly on event. I just need to use invokeAll of ExecutorService. Following code sample can help:

```
public void handleSomeEvent(Event event) {
    List<Task> tasksToRunOnEvent = getTasksToRunOnEvent(event);
    List<Future<TaskResult> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasksToRunOnEvent);
    handleTaskResults(futures);
}
```

Comment: Re-submitting the tasks runs through the execute/schedule code and creates a new task out of the old one (will call a new decorate etc). I can not duplicate the tasks, i need to start the existing instances so that the executor can not run them at the same time (as they are already run and have to be re-submitted).

Comment: What do you mean by 'creates a new task out of the old one'?

Comment: What I meant is that it takes the task and wraps it in a different task. However, overwriting the decorateTask method correctly makes it work. The runnable passed into the method is the previous task. By just returning that one, the correct task can be started.

Answer (score 0):

I took tvelykyy's advice and played around a little bit and came up with this impl:

```
public class EventBasedExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implements EventBasedExecutorService {

    private List<RunnableScheduledFuture<?>> workers = new ArrayList<>();

    private int index;

    public EventBasedExecutor(int corePoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize,  new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).setNameFormat("message-sender-%d").build());
    }

    @Override
    protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Runnable runnable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
        if(!workers.contains(runnable)) {
            workers.add(task);
        }
        return super.decorateTask(runnable, task);
    }

    @Override
    public void executeEarly() {
        if(index >= workers.size()) {
            index = 0;
        }

        if(workers.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        RunnableScheduledFuture<?> runnableScheduledFuture = workers.get(index);
        index ++;
        execute(runnableScheduledFuture);
    }

}
```

A few words:

workers.contains(Runnable) is true, if you re-submit one RunnableScheduledFuture.

You have to submit it through execute to get it to run in the threadpool (rather than just call run on the runnable which will block the current thread).

I recommend the runnables to implement a safety guard so that they can't be executed twice at the same time (important for my usecase). So basically:

```
if( isrunning() ) return;
```

In decorateTask - you must re-decorate the runnable. This is because the implementation will take the wrapped runnable and re-schedule it, if it must. Since the old runnables are already scheduled, you don't want to reschedule them. So calling execute will run through the decoration and decorate the scheduled runnable (which will usually run every second or some) to be a non-repeatable runnable. This means, that your scheduled task can run once without being rescheduled, while still being available as a periodic runnable within the executor.

I hope this all makes sense :)

Artur